# Como mudar CalendarView minTime/maxTime/slotDuration?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Preciso de mudar: SlotDuration para '00:10:00', minTime para '08:00:00, e maxTime para '22:00:00' sem mexer no código original

call_calendar_change.xml

```
<odoo>
<template id="assets_backend name="assets_backend_new" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
<xpath expr="." position="inside">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/anser_ricardo/static/src/js/change_calendar.js"></script>
</xpath>
</template>
</odoo>
```

change_calendar.js

```
odoo.define('anser_ricardo.call_calendar_change', function(require){
"use strict";
var CalendarView = require('web.CalendarView');
CalenderView.include({
minTime: '08:00:00'
maxTime: '22:00:00'
slotDuration: '00:10:00'
})
});
```

Mas o que tenho não funciona, acho que o problema está no.js, alguem me pode ajudar? Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui está a solução:

```
odoo.define('anser_ricardo', function (require) {
"use strict";

var CalendarModel = require('web.CalendarModel');

CalendarModel.include({
    _getFullCalendarOptions: function () {
        var res = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        return _.extend(res, {
            minTime: '08:00:00',
            maxTime: '22:00:00',
            slotDuration: '00:10:00',
        });
    },
});
```